# Image buttons are not working

Tags: android, android-launcher, android-imagebutton

I am pretty new to android programming and I am trying to create a simple home screen replacement/launcher.

The application runs fine and the view pager works, but for some reason when I press on any of the image buttons nothing happens.

This is my main activity java class.

```
package com.dntmdp.matthewhuckel.simplephonelauncher;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button phone;

    Button sms;

    Button people;

    Button camera;

    Button chrome;

    Button gallery;

    Button mail;

    Button calendar;

    Button facebook;

    Button map;

    Button clock;

    Button setting;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.swipe1);

        ImageButton phone = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);

        phone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.phone");

                startActivity(LaunchIntent);
            }
        });

        ImageButton sms = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);

        sms.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.sonyericsson.conversations");

                startActivity(LaunchIntent);
            }
        });

        ImageButton people = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);

        people.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.sonyericsson.android.socialphonebook");

                startActivity(LaunchIntent);
            }
        });

        ImageButton camera = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton4);

        camera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.sonyericsson.android.camera");

                startActivity(LaunchIntent);
            }
        });

        setContentView(R.layout.swipe2);

        ImageButton chrome = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton5);

        chrome.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.chrome");

                startActivity(LaunchIntent);
            }
        });

        ImageButton gallery = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton6);

        gallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.sonyericsson.album");

                startActivity(LaunchIntent);
            }
        });

        ImageButton mail = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton7);

        mail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.email");

                startActivity(LaunchIntent);
            }
        });

        ImageButton calendar = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton8);

        calendar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.calendar");

                startActivity(LaunchIntent);
            }
        });

        ImageButton facebook = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton9);

        facebook.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.facebook.katana");

                startActivity(LaunchIntent);
            }
        });

        ImageButton map = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton10);

        map.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");

                startActivity(LaunchIntent);
            }
        });

        setContentView(R.layout.swipe3);

        ImageButton clock = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton11);

        clock.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.sonyericsson.organizer");

                startActivity(LaunchIntent);
            }
        });

        ImageButton setting = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton12);

        setting.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.settings");

                startActivity(LaunchIntent);
            }
        });

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MyPagerAdapter adapter = new MyPagerAdapter();
        ViewPager myPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager_layout);
        myPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        myPager.setCurrentItem(0);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: pls go through some tutorial or read the docs. You have `setContentView` more than once in the same activity which is not a good idea at all. Each  Activity has its own ui and a lifecycle. You set the layout to the activity with `setContentView`

Answer (score 2):

whenever you switch your layout using `setContentView` you have to re-declare the image button again, it will work only if its available in the new `layout` as it wont work if its not inside that layout. since you are coding launcher using switch `layout` this way is bad, please consider using `Fragment` instead.
P.S your code above  to trigger the `click` is fine but as i mentioned above they wont work if you switched to new layout without re-declaring that `imageButton` again under `setContentView`.

Comment: Do you mind posting an example of a redeclared image button under the set content view?

Comment: its obvious tho , just copy paste your previous click code along with the id declaration, but yet still i don't recommend this such way.

Answer (score -1):

```
imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);

imageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

    Toast.makeText(MyAndroidAppActivity.this,
                   "ImageButton is clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

});
```

Try above code that is working. You do not need to use

```
new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
    }
}
```

Comment: `new View.OnClickListener()` is View's OnClickListner. Its  interface and you implement the interface.  You do not need to use. Why is that??. read http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html

Comment: phone.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.phone");

                startActivity(LaunchIntent);
            }
        });

Answer (score -1):

Check the below code,  It worked for me so i assume it will work with you!:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    ImageView imv_Load;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        imv_Load = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imv_Click);
        imv_Load.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.imv_Click:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Button Clikced",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}
```